# Sending Mail Through Perl

Tags: perl

I am using the below code to send an email

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub BEGIN {
        unshift (@INC,'/opt/dev/common/mds/perlLib');
}

use Mail::Sender;

$sender = new Mail::Sender
{smtp => 'xxx.xxx.x.xx', from => 'abc@xyz.xom'};
$sender->MailFile({to => 'abc@xyz.xom',
subject => 'Here is the file',
msg => "I'm sending you the list you wanted."});

$sender->Close;
```

But, it is not sending the mail at all. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try using strict and warnings (after the #! line, add: "use strict;use warnings;") and fix any warnings that occur; also, post what errors you get.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use that module because MIME::Entity works so much better, but from working with mail, I can tell you that you are getting ahead of yourself, and making assumptions rather than deductions.

perldoc on that module shows several methods -- and MailFile is for attaching and sending files. If it fails when sending a message without an attached file, I'd have to say I'm not surprised. Has that worked anywhere else?

Were you able to make MailMsg() work? If you cannot, (the syntax is very similar but with fewer things to go wrong), then you may have a problem with connecting to server. From the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx bit, I'd have to assume you're using an ip address. Try a hostname. Also, set on_errors to die() or maybe warn(), and see if you can trap the error. Most mail attempts fail during the connect to the server/creation of the object -- then the sending attempt will by definition fail, but often without telling you why.

If you cannot connect, make sure that you aren't needing to authenticate to your server.